# Как обратиться к свойству экземпляра класса через статистический метод?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babel

Всем привет (:

Для начала распишу ситуацию, потому что вопрос на самом деле комплексный.

Пытаюсь сделать для личного сайта один большой класс, который бы реализовывал всю логику сайта в себе самом. То есть в дальнейшем задается конструктор для сайта, и всё. Методы сами собой общаются если нужно, исполняют и реализовывают функционал когда нужно, но в рамках этого класса. Никаких внешних оберток и бесконечных обработчиков.

Причина такая: мне показалось удобным создать такой класс:

```
class Core() {
    // Методы и все такое
}
```

Далее мы инициализируем настройки для сайта **один** раз, и всё, больше не возвращаемся в исходники и не копаемся там, если я решу выводить на странице не 10 постов, а 5, например:

```
var CoreInterface= new Core({
    countPopularTagsToShow: 12,
    // Всякие другие опции
});
```

Но я сталкнулся с такой штукой. Сначала я попытался сделать так:

```
class Core {
    static addError(errorText) {
        this.errors.push(errorText);
    }

    static toDo() {
        // Что-то делаем, что-то фейлится, пытаемся записать в лог.
        Core.addError(errorText);
    }

    constructor(){
        this.errors = [];
        Core.toDo();
    }
}
```

Зачем мне это надо? Мне бы хотелось иметь доступ к некоторым текущим (по ходу действия работы класса самого по себе) свойствам экземпляра класса. Я это показываю на примере ошибок, но в принципе, даже для отладки хотелось бы иметь такой доступ к свойствам из глобального контекста.
Почему не хочу все сделать публичным? Ну потому что. Не хочу, чтобы любой Васян имел доступ к методам. Хочу закрытый как Пентагон класс на своём сайте.

Ну окей (подумал я), раз обратиться к свойству экземпляра из статического метода класса нельзя, то какие альтернативы?
Вот так я и поступил:

```
class Core {
    static echoErrors() {
        console.error(Core.errors);
    }

    static addError(errorText) {
        Core.errors.push(errorText);
        Core.echoErrors();
    }

    static toDo() {
        // Что-то делаем, что-то фейлится, пытаемся записать в лог.
        Core.addError(errorText);
    }

    constructor(){
        Core.errors = [];
        this.echoErrors = Core.echoErrors;
    }
}
```

Я привязал к экземпляру класса Core метод echoErrors, который статический и типа у которого есть доступ только у Core.  Тем не менее, мы имеем доступ к методу по привязке в строке `this.echoErrors = Core.echoErrors`.

Так вот, вопрос в том, всё ли правильно я сделал? Верно ли решил ситуацию с вызовом из статических методов класса к свойствам экземпляра? Или, может быть, есть более правильный подход? По-моему я сломал саму концепцию статических методов, привязав стат. метод к экземпляру.
Но я правда другого пути не вижу. Все методы статические

Comment: Надеюсь хоть кто-то поймет то, что ты написал.... А вообще, тебе наверное нужен был синглтон.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну да, мне это и нужно. Но только с классом... Можешь привести пример, пожалуйста? Чтобы использовался класс, доступ к методам которого был только только у самого класса, но можно было бы обращаться к экземпляру (и записывать в него свойства) в методах класса.